# Variable seems to keep it's initial value in if statement - PHP, SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, variables, simplexml

I have the following PHP code which should store the index of a single customer matched with an XPath expression in `$customerIndexOfMatch` and then uses `$customerIndexOfMatch` to edit the XML values of the customer located at that index.

My issue is that `$customerIndexOfMatch` gives the expected value but only outside of the `if (isset($_POST['updateCustomer']))` statement and I'm not sure why it's doing this.

```
<?php
$customerIndexOfMatch = -1;

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchTerm = $_POST['searchTerm'];
    $searchBy = $_POST['search-by'];
    if (isset($searchBy)) {
        if ($searchBy == "Last Name") {
            $precedingCount = $customersXml->xpath('//customer/customerInfo/lastName[text()="' . $searchTerm . '"]/preceding::customer');
            $ancestorCount = $customersXml->xpath('//customer/customerInfo/lastName[text()="' . $searchTerm . '"]/ancestor-or-self::customer');
            $customerIndexOfMatch = (count($precedingCount) + count($ancestorCount));
        }
        elseif ($searchBy == "Customer Number") {
            $precedingCount = $customersXml->xpath('//customer[@number="' . $searchTerm . '"]/preceding::customer');
            $ancestorCount = $customersXml->xpath('//customer[@number="' . $searchTerm . '"]/ancestor-or-self::customer');
            $customerIndexOfMatch = (count($precedingCount) + count($ancestorCount));
        }
        elseif ($searchBy == "Meter Number") {
            $precedingCount = $customersXml->xpath('//customer[@meterNumber="' . $searchTerm . '"]/preceding::customer');
            $ancestorCount = $customersXml->xpath('//customer[@meterNumber="' . $searchTerm . '"]/ancestor-or-self::customer');
            $customerIndexOfMatch = (count($precedingCount) + count($ancestorCount));
        }
    }
}

// var_dump($customerIndexOfMatch); // not -1, gives expected value
// die();

$fname = someDataFromAForm
$mname = someDataFromAForm
$lname = someDataFromAForm
$address = someDataFromAForm
$ph1 = someDataFromAForm
$ph2 = someDataFromAForm
$ph3 = someDataFromAForm

// var_dump($customerIndexOfMatch); // not -1, gives expected value
// die();

if (isset($_POST['updateCustomer'])) {
    // edit the details and write to file
    $customersXml = simplexml_load_file('customers.xml', null, true) or die('Error: Cannot load XML from file customers.xml"');

    // The value of $customerIndexOfMatch isn't the expected value, therefore I cannot properly write the edited data to file
    // $customerIndexOfMatch represents the index of the customer that is to be edited. $customerIndexOfMatch isn't 0 based.
    // the value of the index before this if statement is correct but in the if statement it is -1

    // var_dump($customerIndexOfMatch); // -1, the default value for $customerIndexOfMatch
    // die();

    /*
    $customersXml->customer[$customerIndexOfMatch]->customerInfo->firstName = $fname;
    $customersXml->customer[$customerIndexOfMatch]->customerInfo->middleName = $mname;
    $customersXml->customer[$customerIndexOfMatch]->customerInfo->lastName = $lname;
    $customersXml->customer[$customerIndexOfMatch]->customerInfo->address = $address;
    $customersXml->customer[$customerIndexOfMatch]->customerInfo->telephone[0] = $ph1;
    $customersXml->customer[$customerIndexOfMatch]->customerInfo->telephone[1] = $ph2;
    $customersXml->customer[$customerIndexOfMatch]->customerInfo->telephone[2] = $ph3;
    $customersXml->asXML('customers.xml')
    */
}

// the html form where someDataFromAForm comes from
```

Are there any reasons as to why `$customerIndexOfMatch` keeps it's initial value when in the `if (isset($_POST['updateCustomer']))` block, but before the block it has it's expected value? What options do I have to fix this issue? Still fairly new to PHP, can't see why it's doing this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure it's not being run twice for some reason, but you're under the impression that all the output is from one run? Add some logging to the very beginning of the script to check.

Comment: @AndrewCheong Thanks for the feedback. Just checked then and it doesn't seem to be running twice. Would it be possible that once the 'search' button has been clicked that the $customerIndexOfMatch gets set to its value but then the page refreshes because its a form which causes the values to be reinitialised? Or should the values still be stored after the form has been submitted?

Comment: From the code (and I'm not new to PHP), I don't see how it's possible. Did you remove any code to minimize the example? If not, I would look toward something outside the code, to be the culprit.

Comment: Update: I've come up with a workaround. What I did was chang the lines where I've set the value of $customerIndexOfMatch to be $_SESSION['index'] = ... 
instead and it does keep the value.

Comment: That actually all the more points to your code being run twice, and now the $_SESSION happens to be preserving the value across runs.